# How to add multiple content roots in IntelliJ IDEA module using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

My setup includes two projects. One is a base project with all the necessary sources and another one is an admin project, which includes the base one and adds additional sources.

The setup looks like the following:

```
admin
│
├-base
│ ├-src
│ │ └-main (2)
│ │   ├-java
│ │   └-resources
│ └-build.gradle
│
├-src (1)
│ └-main (3)
│   ├-java
│   └-resources
├-build.gradle
└-settings.gradle
```

(n) numbers refer to the image attached below.

**admin/settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = "sample-admin"
include('base')
```

**admin/build.gradle**

```
group "sample.admin"
version "1"

project(":base") {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += file("../src/main/java")
    sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs += file("../src/main/resources")
}
```

**admin/base/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

application {
    mainClass = 'demo.App'
}
```

and IntelliJ IDEA see it as

[image]

So, **how to make (1) to be as (2) and include (3)?**

Answer (score 0):

The IDE loads the gradle build file and then creates modules in the Project Structure. Users modify the build file to adjust the project structure instead of modifying it from the IDE Project Structure dialog so that every time the IDE loads the project correctly.

Does the sample feed your expectation?
[image]

Comment: Ethan Yin, thank you for the answer. It does not comply. Your example produces two modules `gradle-jar-artifact.base.main` and `gradle-jar-artifact.main`. I require to have a single module within the "base" project which includes additional sources from the "admin" project into the same `admin.base.main` module.